# Can't add component to layout

Tags: java, layout, vaadin, vaadin7

hi all I'm having a strange problem, but I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.
In a maven project I have my UI class as below:

```
package my.vaadin.project.exceptionTest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Widgetset;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("my.vaadin.project.exceptionTest.MyAppWidgetset")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        final Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
        final Label title = new Label("Calculation");       
        layout.addComponents(title, calculation);       
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);        
        setContent(layout);
    }
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

And then I have another class which holds various fields that I then attempt to add to the UI, unsuccessfully:

```
package my.vaadin.project.exceptionTest;
import java.awt.Component;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.event.Action;
public class Calculation extends CustomComponent{
    final VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
    final TextField divisor = new TextField();
    final TextField dividend = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button("Click Me"); 
    public Calculation(){
        divisor.setCaption("Enter the divisor:");
        dividend.setCaption("Enter the dividend:");
        button.addClickListener( new Button.ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                System.out.println("this is a test");               
            }            
        });     
        vl.setMargin(true);
        vl.setSpacing(true);
        vl.addComponents(divisor, dividend, button );
    }
}
```

So my question is, when in the UI class I do

```
layout.addComponents(title, calculation);
```

I get an error saying: "The method addComponents(Component...) in the type AbstractComponentContainer is not applicable for the arguments (Label, Calculation)"
I've done something similar before, like creating an object of a separate class and add it to the layout and it has worked, this time it doesn't and I'm not sure what it is that I've done wrong...any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method `addComponents(...)` only accepts `Component`as arguments.
Your `Calculation` class does not extend/implement `Component`

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponentContainer.html#addComponents(com.vaadin.ui.Component...)

Comment: @antobbo For your own components, the base class CustomComponent is best practise. See [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-customcomponent.html).

Comment: If I use `extends Component`, it still complaints and gives me an error where I use addComponents(), but if I instead do `extends CustomComponent` it seems OK, in the sense that the compiler is OK with that. Trouble is, my fields still don't appear. So, I had a look at the link @SteffenHarbich and I tried to apply that to my code. I have epdated the classes in the thread

Comment: right, looks like I figured that out. Apparently just adding the object as in `layout.addComponents(title, calculation);` doesn't work but I have to specify the object's property to add, like `layout.addComponents(title, calculation.button, calculation.divisor, calculation.dividend, calculation.result);`. I find this a little strange though, I would have thought I could add the object to the layout directly

Comment: You can add your component (let's say X) derived from CustomComponent directly. Then set a layout like VerticalLayout or HorizontalLayout as composition root of X and add your components to that layout. This is the usual way.